# Geth Accounts - Sending Transactions across nodes

Tags: go-ethereum

I am using GETH and have deployed a private block chain. One thing I came across is that accounts are attached to nodes and when I attach with a particular node say Node A, I am not able to send transactions from accounts created on Node B to other accounts. Sending transactions from accounts in Node A to any account works fine.

Is there a way I can solve this issue or is this a limitation from GETH. To my knowledge blockchain accounts are independent from the nodes so I am a bit confused

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It is likely you are using account created in each node. So node A can only sign transactions for accounts created in node  A and you cannot send a transaction from node B for accounts created in node A.

One solution is to import the private keys created in node A in a custodial wallet like MyEtherWallet, MyCrypto, Metamask, etc., that way you are managing the private keys by yourself independently of the nodes.